# run function after filename

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, path

I want to run different functions depending on the filename

This is my code:

```
    entries = Path(infile)
    for file in sorted(entries.glob("*.TXT")): 
        if file == '*Blk.TXT':
            outlier.outlier_Cu_blk(file)
        elif file == '*s0*.TXT':
            outlier.outlier_Cu_std(file)
        else:
            outlier.outlier_Cu_sample(file)
```

But it is just calling "else", even with the files containing "Blk.TXT" and "s0". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`==` doesn't take in `*` as separators, if you want to do this further, you need to consider using regex.

```
entries = Path(infile)
for file in sorted(entries.glob("*.TXT")): 
    file = str(file)
    if file.endswith('Blk.TXT'):
        outlier.outlier_Cu_blk(file)
    elif file.endswith('.TXT') and 's0' in file:
        outlier.outlier_Cu_std(file)
    else:
        outlier.outlier_Cu_sample(file)
```

Answer (score 3):

The '==' didn't use regex like matching, you should use `re` for this purpose:

```python
import re
blk_txt_rgx = re.compile(r'.*Blk\.TXT')
s0_txt_rgx = re.compile(r'.*s0.*\.TXT')

entries = Path(infile)
for file in sorted(entries.glob("*.TXT")): 
    if blk_txt_rgx.match(file):
        outlier.outlier_Cu_blk(file)
    elif s0_txt_rgx.match(file):
        outlier.outlier_Cu_std(file)
    else:
        outlier.outlier_Cu_sample(file)
```

Comment: this is much  better, the fact that i just mentioned `regex` and seeing a regex answer right after

Comment: Thx! But I got the error "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object".

Answer (score 0):

Python does not support wildcards like * in a normal string. can use a regex to do this. A wildcard character that can represent one arbitrary char is the dot (`.`). To repeat this multiple times we can add a `*`. make sure to add a backslash (`\`) to escape the dot in your filename.

```
import re
blk_regex = re.compile(r'.*Blk\.TXT')
slk_regex = re.compile(r'.*s0.*\.TXT')

for file in sorted(entries.glob("*.TXT")): 
if blk_regex.match(file):
    outlier.outlier_Cu_blk(file)
elif slk_regex.match(file):
    outlier.outlier_Cu_std(file)
else:
    outlier.outlier_Cu_sample(file)
```